# AutoFill Textfields in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to autofill textfields based on other textfields on Flutter? I have a unique user id and when I enter that user id, if the user exists, I want to populate the fields with the details of the user. If it doesn't, I want to be able to manually enter the fields. How can I implement it in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely take a look at a package called [flutter_form_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_bloc). Specifically, the async prefilled examples. If you're familiar with the BLoC pattern, it should work great. Even if you aren't you will catch on quick. For me personally, I had no idea what the BLoC pattern was but I quickly got the hang of it. Personally, I think this is the best way to go about it.

If you have more questions, ask me in the comments.

Comment: Sounds legit. I am not that into bloc, infact I have only used bloc to monitor network status. But sound about time to get into it. Thank you for your suggestion.